# Apache Server Problem? can't access apache server in Guest OS from Host OS when using vmware

Tags: apache, centos, apache-config

Here is the situation:

-Using VMWare Workstation, set the network adapter to bridge.
-Host os is winxp, guest os is CentOS 5
-Apache server installed in guest (centos) os
-Say my host ip:`172.19.20.100`, my guest ip:`172.19.20.101`

My host installed rails, so I just type 'rails server' in command line, it started up a server.I can access that in my guest os when I typing `172.19.20.100:3000` into the browser.

But when I started Apache server in guest, I can't access that in host when I typing `172.19.20.101` into the browser. If I type `172.19.20.101` in the guest, it does work...And `ping 172.19.20.101` in the host command line also works.

So I guess something goes wrong in the apache server. But I comapred the httpd.conf with some tutorials and didn't see anything unusual.

Please give some advice.

Comment: There is a [Windows Installer](http://rubyonrails.org/download) for rails, and [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) as apache server for windows, both as installer. It might take a moment or two to get them installed, but it's well worth the effort, since you wouldn't have to deal with virtualization-related problems that way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll give it a try. I know in this case virtual machine is not MUST needed, and xampp is definitely an option. But since the real server(deploy-target) is a centos, having a relatively same environment would be helpful for some purposes.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. However, for the development process itself, a Virtual machine is not required, so I would recommend using xampp+rails.

Comment: I've installed XAMPP and configured the server, setup memcache etc. And that make the vmware go away. My development process get smoother and faster than before. Anyway, I think it's good to take another way to achieve the goal, though I still wonder why I can't make it through vmware. Thanks @nebukadnezzar!

Comment: I could form my comment as an answer, so you could accept it (if you don't mind :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Windows Installer](http://rubyonrails.org/download) for rails, and [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) as apache server for windows, both as installer.

It might take a moment or two to get them installed, but it's well worth the effort, since you wouldn't have to deal with virtualization-related problems that way.